# django 1.7 migrate gets error "table already exists"

Tags: django, django-south, django-1.7, django-migrations

I am trying to apply a migration but am getting the error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'customers_customer'
>   already exists")

I get this by issuing the following command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

My customer table already exists, so what do I do to let the migration know this, not error out, and run my modification to my model?

I ran this on my local environment with local database with no problem.  It is when I pointed my database to production and ran `migrate` above that I get this error.

Comment: One question - Should you not be using the django migrations instead of south for django 1.7?

Comment: That error is a django migrations error.

Comment: @karthikr I am using django migrations.  I used a south tag on this question because I thought someone in that community might know the answer.

Comment: I think I faced a similar issue. If you run python manage.py syncdb then later run the manage.py migrate, it results in that, because syncdb also kinda creates those tables. The recommend approach would be to run this, assuming you have no database: python manage.py migrate <app_name>. Then if you wanna create superuser, you do python manage.py createsuperuser.

Comment: I have the same problem. Nothing worked so far. It seems I killed a mechanism by deleting the migration directory and database file. I thought deleting those files would be ok, to start from scratch, but apparently it is not.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

If you have the table created in the database, you can run

```
python manage.py migrate --fake <appname>
```

*Mark migrations as run without actually running them*

Or if you want to avoid some actions in your migration, you can edit the migration file under the app/migrations directory and comment the operations you don't want to do in the migrate execution.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south
or `python manage.py help migrate`

Comment: ^Works in Django 1.11

Comment: I hope no issues will come due to this

Comment: This worked. However, part of what was in the fake was a new table to the database. To solve this, I forced another migration by adding a field to the new table. Then I edited the new migration and added the table creation in the new migration and removed the new field that I didn't need. This produced my new table and keep the migration path going. The --fake gave me something to start with. Thank you.

Comment: Still works in Django 4.1

Answer (score 23):

Its actually `python manage.py migrate --fake <appname>`

Answer (score 11):

> We can solve this issue in two way as mentioned in answer:
>   1.) By editing in migration file
>
> We have migrations folder created in each application we create, In
>   those migration folder the migration file(0001_initial.py is the
>   initially created and after this all other files dependent on this
>   initial file will be create), When we run the python manage.py
>   migrate, For every APP the migration file will apply if there is
>   change in the file. We can see this run Applying on terminal after the
>   migrate command. If there is any issue in migration file we use to get
>   the error at that point. In my/our case:

```
Applying ValetUser.0002_keyroundslots_systemparameters_vehicleparking_vehicleparkingdetails...Traceback (most recent call last):
sqlite3.OperationalError: table "valet_keyroundslots" already exists
```

> Here we can notice that the file in which we have issue is mentioned
>   i.e ValetUser.0002_keyroundslots_systemparameters, So we can Go to the
>   App and then migrations and in 0002 file we can Comment the
>   CreateModel Operation of That particular Model in which we are facing issue while
>   applying migrations.
>   example:

```
operations = [
    # migrations.CreateModel(
    #     name='KeyRoundSlots',
    #     fields=[
    #         ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
    #         ('key_round', models.IntegerField()),
    #         ('key_slot', models.IntegerField()),
    #         ('is_available', models.BooleanField()),
    #         ('Valet_id', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='valet_location', to='ValetUser.ValetAt')),
    #     ],
    #     options={
    #         'db_table': 'valet_keyroundslots',
    #     },
    # ),
```

> 2.) By applying fake migration of the modified migration file of the particular APP in which we are facing the error/issue, --fake will
>   apply the fake migration that will not effect to the already applied
>   migration of the model.

```
python manage.py migrate --fake <appname>
```

> The answers given Waqas and elmonkeylp are also right, I just wanna
>   explain it in brief with the help of we use to scenario

Comment: @elmonkeylp why not delete the whole file that is bringing in issues instead of commenting its sections?

Comment: This is a great answer - but is there a way to make the model creation essentially optional? We have dev and prod databases that are live and have this model, directly created in SQL; but meanwhile we also have unit tests that create a DB on the fly, and our local server databases on developers' machines. There's no solution where all of these machines either have the model or don't have the model; and our migration scripts for server deployment don't allow for --fake. Is there a way we can indicate that the model may exist, so only create it if not?