# Can't migrate after makemigrations on django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

everyone. I newbie in this field. So, After I finished makemigrations. then I migrate this error code occurs. I try to solve it but still stuck. please guide, I attach my error code as below.

```
(venv) C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\src>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, house, oauth2_provider, sessions, social_django, task, users
Running migrations:
  Applying task.0002_auto_20210331_2329...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 411, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table "task_tasklist" already exists

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 324, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Taskly_App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 411, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "task_tasklist" already exists
```

I don't know task_tasklist error is mean.

Please help me!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django 1.7 migrate gets error "table already exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924858/django-1-7-migrate-gets-error-table-already-exists)

Answer (score 0):

The error message speak for itself:

The table "task_tasklist" already exists in our DB

Comment: Thank you so much, for your guideline.