# TransactionManagementError in Django when make migrate

Tags: python, django, transactions, virtualenv

I am new to programming , I have an issue when make migrate in Django 3.2.9.

Here is my code, models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE, PROTECT

# Create your models here.


class Promotion(models.Model):
   description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   discount = models.FloatField()


class Collection(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Product(models.Model):
   slug = models.SlugField()
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   description = models.TextField()
   unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
   inventory = models.IntegerField()
   last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   promotions = models.ManyToManyField(Promotion)


class Customer(models.Model):
   MEMBERSHIP_BRONZE = 'B'
   MEMBERSHIP_SILVER = 'S'
   MEMBERSHIP_GOLD = 'G'

   MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES = [
       (MEMBERSHIP_BRONZE, 'Bronze'),
       (MEMBERSHIP_SILVER, 'Silver'),
       (MEMBERSHIP_GOLD, 'Gold')

   ]

   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
   membership = models.CharField(
       max_length=1, choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES, default=MEMBERSHIP_BRONZE)


class Order(models.Model):

   STATUS_Pending = 'P'
   STATUS_Complete = 'C'
   STATUS_Failed = 'F'

   STATUS_CHOICES = [
       (STATUS_Pending, 'Pending'),
       (STATUS_Complete, 'Complete'),
       (STATUS_Failed, 'Failed')
   ]

   placed_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_date=True)
   payment_status = models.CharField(
       max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=STATUS_Pending)

   customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=PROTECT)


class Address(models.Model):
   street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   customer = models.OneToOneField(
       Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
   order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=PROTECT)
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=PROTECT)
   quantiy = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
   unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)


class Cart(models.Model):
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class CartItem(models.Model):
   cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=CASCADE)
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=CASCADE)
   quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

I successfully run : python manage.py makemigrations
But when I run:python manage.py migrate,
I encoutered an issues

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, likes, store, tags
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: django_migrations.applied

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 229, in apply_migration
    self.record_migration(migration)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in record_migration
    self.recorder.record_applied(migration.app_label, migration.name)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 87, in record_applied
    self.migration_qs.create(app=app, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: django_migrations.applied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FR\Python_VScode\django_app\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\FR\Python_VScode\django_app\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line     
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 230, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.connection.check_constraints()
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 329, in check_constraints
    violations = cursor.execute('PRAGMA foreign_key_check').fetchall()
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 78, in _execute
    self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
  File "C:\Users\FR\.virtualenvs\django_app-u_SNPGdA\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 454, in validate_no_broken_transaction   
    raise TransactionManagementError(
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
((django_app) ) PS C:\Users\FR\Python_VScode\django_app>
```

Can someone explain it to me? I am new to programming, more than 4 months. I am using Django 3.2.9.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In your migrations.py folder,you can try deleting manually all the files except 0001_initial.py file. Then run,

```
python manage.py makemigrations <appname> 
python manage.py migrate <appname>
```

This might probably solve your issue.

Comment: hey, SANGEETH SUBRAMONIAM, I tried to follow your steps but I still get stuck when run : python manage.py migrate <appname>,

Comment: try setting null=True for all attributes except primary hey and then make migration  and then migrate

Comment: Hey, It still can't work. when I set the attributes except  primary key with True, and run make migrations, but when I run: migrate, it shows the error: ` django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "store_cart" already exists
`

Comment: check here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924858/django-1-7-migrate-gets-error-table-already-exists