# How to solve django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table '###' already exists") error when running tests in Django

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-testing

I am working with `django.test` package in my project, and have implemented some testcases. I have a MySQL database, and have created a test database with no problem.

But now when I am running my tests it shows the below error.

```
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_sepantadb', or 'no' to cancel: Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1007, "Can't create database 'test_sepantadb'; database exists")
```

And after I type yes to the console, it shows the below errors, and I don't know how to solve them.

```
Destroying old test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ABDAL\SepantaEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "D:\ABDAL\SepantaEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "D:\ABDAL\SepantaEnv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "D:\ABDAL\SepantaEnv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "D:\ABDAL\SepantaEnv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "D:\ABDAL\SepantaEnv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "D:\ABDAL\SepantaEnv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "D:\ABDAL\SepantaEnv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "D:\ABDAL\SepantaEnv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "D:\ABDAL\SepantaEnv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'react_arimapredictedvalues' already exists")
```

I have tried the solution which have been provided in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51743439/20285050). But it does not solve it for me.

I have also run the below command for the second time in my MySQL shell to check the privileges, but again nothing does not change.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_sepantadb.* TO 'sepanta'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I have also tried two other solutions. I have deleted the test databse from `mysql` shell with command prompt, and also change my test database name, but none of these two solutions solved my problem.

These are also the content of my `django_migrations` table in `test_sepantadb` database:
[image]

I will be grateful for any help or advice on how to solve this error.

Comment: check the `migrations` table in your test database and compare with your migration files order. See if there are any different

Comment: Where can I find my test migrations?@LinhNguyen

Comment: in your database, there a should be a database with the name end with _test , check the migrations table for the migration order

Comment: No, actually there is not. I have checked my `django_migrations` table in my local database, but there was no migration related to test database. Also I have executed `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands to sync database changes, but the error still exists...@LinhNguyen

Comment: i don't mean your main database, django will create a new test database https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database. Please check again

Comment: I know it is too late, but I have updated my post. May you please take a look at it?@LinhNguyen